# How to check the end of an asynchronous process from a web browser ?

Tags: jquery, asynchronous

i have a php/jQuery web site which provides the way to launch processes on the server in asynchronous mode.

When I click on a specific link, the server launches a process through php and returns a page telling that the process is started and it displays a hourglass.

If we click on the hourglass, there is an ajax query to ask the server if the process is ended.

But is it possible, and how, with jQuery or pure javascript to make a timer to automatically check the server (send the same ajax query) every 30 seconds ?  The timer should stop when the process is ended.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is: [Javascript timer](http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/setinterval-example/)
But there are callbacks of ajax requests, which returns when the process is ended.

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {         
                //this returns when your ajax process is ended with no error.          
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                //this returns when ajax process ended with error
            }           
   });
```

So you don't have to ping the server for gettind the info: "Are you ready yet?"

Comment: I had not said that the first query is not ajax. It is a normal .php call which launches an asynchronous task but returns a full web page. I should convert that to a Ajax call to use the callback.  But the Timeout can be interesting for me and examples are nice, thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

how about using a more simple version of jquery

```
$.post("test.php", { name: "someName", time: "2pm" })
.done(function(data) {
  alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

the arguments name and time are the element of the request , you can use them in .php file as traditional way like `$_POST['name']`

and the response of the .php file will be retrived in the data variable

Answer (score 0):

jQuery AJAX helpers will provide a facility for a callback that can execute when the asynchronous request finishes.

as per http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

The anonymous function above doesn't run until the GET request to test.html is complete.